# How to resolve error: Argument 1 must have names when using map( ) pluck( ) in R to list( )?

Tags: r, purrr

I have this:

```
list(list(result="0001"),list(result="0002")) %>%
purrr::map(pluck, 'result') %>% 
dplyr::bind_rows()
```

output: Error: Argument 1 must have names.

The error occurs because the result in the list result **"0001"** and **"0002"** have the same name **[1]**, output:

```
[[1]]
[[1]]$result
[1] "0001" <---- [1]

[[2]]
[[2]]$result
[1] "0002" <---- [1]
```

How to restart dianically for n cases the name? Expected Output:

```
[[1]]
[[1]]$result
[1] "0001" <---- [1]

[[2]]
[[2]]$result
[2] "0002" <---- [2]
```

Possibly it must be some transform or function  between map() and bind_rows()

```
purrr::map(pluck, 'result') %>%
???? 
dplyr::bind_rows()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To `bind_rows()`, you just need to convert the list of vectors into a list of `dataframe` beforehand. So, you could do:

**Reprex**

- Code

```r
library(purrr)
library(dplyr)

list(list(result="0001"),list(result="0002")) %>%
  purrr::map(pluck, 'result') %>% 
  purrr::map(., ~ data.frame(results = .)) %>% 
  bind_rows()
```

- Output

```r
#>   results
#> 1    0001
#> 2    0002
```

<sup>Created on 2022-03-04 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>